# pagination route code igniter not working 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function add_template(){
 $this->load->library('pagination');
     $config = array();
     $config['base_url'] =site_url('hradmin/dashboard/add_template');
     $config['total_rows'] = $this->hradvalid->add_temprow();
     $config['per_page'] = 2;
     $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
     $config['uri_segment']  = 4;
     $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm1>";
     $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
     $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
     $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
     $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
     $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
     $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
     $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
     $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
     $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
     $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
     $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
     $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='active'><a>";
     $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
     $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['page']="hradmin/add_template";
    $data['template']=$this->hradvalid->hrget_product($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
    $this->load->view('hradmin/dashboard',$data);
     }
```

this is route code in `config/routes.php`

```
  `$route['hradmin'] = 'hradmin/admin';
  $route['hradmin/admin/dashboard/add_template:num'] ='hradmin/admin/dashboard/add_template/$1';`
```

`hradmin` this is my directory name in views directory

`admin` this is my controller 
    `dashboard` this is method in `admin` controller and another method in same controller is `add template` in this method my pagination file are there.

pagination working showing but click on pagination number  error 404 
please help me thanks

Comment: $config['uri_segment']  = 4;
Try changing your uri_segment to whatever segment your pagenumber is in.

Comment: i have try up to 6 not working

Comment: Try: (:num) instead of :num see manual: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with drilling down your URI segments to make sure they're right but here are some things i've noticed with your code.

1. You don't need to set the $config variable as an array. (`$config = array();`) - you can remove that line.
2. `$config['total_rows'] = $this->hradvalid->add_temprow();`  ... the function name looks like its adding a row. $config['total_rows'] should be an interger with the total available rows.
3. You're setting the base_url as `site_url('hradmin/dashboard/add_template')` but your routes are for `site_url(hradmin/admin/dashboard/add_template:num)` (extra admin URI segment).
4. use (:num) in your routing instead of :num

EDIT, If I had to take a stab at this, i'd say your $config['base_url'] and $config['uri_segment'] var's, along with your routing params, are incorrect.